# How to prove Peano induction axiom for a candidate model

Tags: logic, induction, peano-axioms

Suppose you have a candidate structure, and you want to prove it satisfies the Peano axioms. For example, let 1 serve as the first element, and let $s(x)=x/(1+x)$. It's easy to see the non-induction axioms are satisfied, but how would one show the induction axiom (2nd order) or axiom schema (1st order) is satisfied?

Comment: Which one is the model? You need to define which are all its elements. So far you specified the first element and $S$.

Comment: Since $s(p/q) = p/(p + q)$, you get (by successive application of $s$) : $1/1 \to 1/2 \to 1/3 \to 1/4 \dots$.  So peano axiom applies if and only if your domain is exactly all positive unit fractions.

Comment: If you begin with a set $S$ and a function $f \colon S \to S$ that has no finite orbits, and then choose some element $1 \in S$ and let $M = \{ f^{n}(1) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then $(M,f)$ will always be a model of the Peano Axioms. Any subset of $M$ that contains $1$ and is closed under $f$ must be all of $M$, by falling back on the induction principle on $\mathbb{N}$.